# Python hashing with string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make a function that takes a string(key) and returns the slot number the hash table.
Such that:

```
for key_word in ["John","Jane"]:
    print(key_word, special_hash(key_word, 13)) 
>>> John 8 
    Jane 4
```

The function needs to convert each letter of the string to number form using alphabet position(eg. a=1, b= 2, c=3, etc). So the hash will be: John = 10+15+8+14= 47 -----> = 47 % tablesize(13)

Comment: What is `tablesize`?

Comment: do "J" and "j" hash the same?

Comment: @thefourtheye -- I think that tablesize is `13`.

Comment: @mgilson But it looks like a function call. But based on the output, `tablesize` is 13 only I guess

Comment: no, the function needs to convert the string to lowercase, convert each letter of the string to ASCII - 96, sum those numbers up and get the remainder of the sum % table_size. I just dont know how to format it all.

Comment: There's a hash library in python, why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the string to lowercase with `lower` function and iterate through the characters in the word, with a `for` loop, like this

```
def special_hash(word, tablesize):
    for char in word.lower():
        ...
```

Then, you can get the character code corresponding to the character with [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#ord) function.

```
def special_hash(word, tablesize):
    total_value = 0
    for char in word.lower():
        total_value += ord(char) - ord('a') + 1
```

Since we need to get the offset of the character in the alphabets, you can subtract the first value from the current value. Then finally, you can use modulo operator `%` to get the remainder of the division by `tablesize`

```
def special_hash(word, tablesize):
    total_value = 0
    for char in word.lower():
        total_value += ord(char) - ord('a') + 1
    return total_value % tablesize
```

The same can be written succintly with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum) function, like this

```
def special_hash(word, tablesize):
    return sum(ord(char) - ord('a') + 1 for char in word.lower()) % tablesize
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord` function and substract the ascii offset (a letter is 97 code, b is 98, and so on)

```
>>> ascii_offset = ord('a')-1 #http://www.asciitable.com/
>>> def special_hash(word, tablesize):
...     return sum([ord(c) - ascii_offset for c in word.lower() ]) % tablesize
... 
>>> special_hash('John',13)
8
>>> ##47%13 -> 8
```

Comment: Thank you. I got so many errors trying to get the structure right but that works.